# DB2 UTF8 storage configuration

Tags: database, utf-8, db2

I have DB2 database, and I have already defined tables with `varchar(x)`, but it seems that `x` - is not the number of characters but the number of bytes. Is it possible to fix the issue somehow dynamically? or should I update my tables?

Comment: I don't think it is an "issue" -- it is well documented behaviour. The answer depends on the DB2 version and platform, which you did not indicate.

Comment: db2 v10.5 and I am running it on Win. I read that I can use VARGRAPHIC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 characters can be represented by byte sequences that are 1 to 4 bytes long, so it is impossible to know in advance the maximum byte length of a UTF-8 string that contains `x` Unicode characters.

Beginning with DB2 10.5 fix pack 4 (the so called "Cancun release") you can [specify string length units](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0060911.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F1-0-9-15-0&lang=en) when defining columns: `VARCHAR(x OCTETS)` would mean x bytes; `VARCHAR(x CODEUNITS16)` would mean x two-byte characters, and `VARCHAR(x CODEUNITS32)` would mean x four-byte characters.

If you don't specify units explicitly, the default is derived from the `string_units` database configuration parameter and from the `NLS_STRING_UNITS` global variable.

`GRAPHIC` and `VARGRAPHIC` data types are also subject to the same unit specification, although the default unit for them is 2-byte characters, not octets.

Note that character and CLOB columns are still subject to the same length limitations as before: for example, the maximum length of a `VARCHAR` column is 32672 bytes (`OCTETS`), or 16336 `CODEUNITS16`, or 8168 `CODEUNITS32`.

Comment: so basically I need to set CODEUNITS32 in string units, am I right?

Comment: I cannot tell you what you need to do, because I don't know your requirements. I hope the information I provided helps you make a decision.

Comment: I have installed fx4 and set string_utils to codeunit32, so it is working now, thank you!